# Index type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to understand and effectively use the index type available in elasticsearch.
However, I am still not clear how _type meta field is different from any regular field of an index in terms of storage/implementation. I do understand [avoiding_type_gotchas](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html#_avoiding_type_gotchas)

For example, if I have 1 million records (say posts) and each post has a creation_date. How will things play out if one of my index types is creation_date itself (leading to ~ 1 million types)? I don't think it affects the way Lucene stores documents, does it?
In what way my elasticsearch query performance be affected if I use creation_date as index type against a namesake type say 'post'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465668/elastic-search-multiple-indexes-vs-one-index-and-types-for-different-data-sets

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on elastic forum.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-type-effective-utilization/58706

Pasting the response as is -

"While elasticsearch is scalable in many dimensions there is one where it is limited. This is the metadata about your indices which includes the various indices, doc types and fields they contain.
These "mappings" exist in memory and are updated and shared around all nodes with every change. For this reason it does not make sense to endlessly grow the list of indices, types (and therefore fields) that exist in this cluster state. A type-per-document-creation-date registers a million on the one-to-ten scale of bad design decisions" - Mark_Harwood