# How to add new type inside existing index using Nest?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest to commuicate with ElasticSearch indexes.

Now, I am trying to add new type inside existing index :

```
    if (elasticClient.IndexExists("catalogindex").Exists)
        {
            var request = new TypeExistsRequest("catalogindex", "product");
            if (!elasticClient.TypeExists(request).Exists)
            {
               //here I want to add the mapping for my product type
            }
        }
```

So Is there any method I can use to do that?

P.S

I know that there is CreateIndex() method but what if I want to add new type to that index without recreating the whole index.

Comment: I'd advised against doing so because ES 6 (released two days ago) won't allow to have [more than one type per index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html) so your code would not be forward compatible when you upgrade to ES 6.

Comment: I have read here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465668/elastic-search-multiple-indexes-vs-one-index-and-types-for-different-data-sets that there are some trade-offs of having multiple types over one per index!!

Comment: Yes, but that question is 4 years old and in ES 6 it won't be possible anymore, so the question won't stand anymore.

Comment: @Val another thing they have mentioned that indexes built using versions 5.x will still work but you cannot have multiple types per index . and what if indexes are built using versions < 4.x?

Comment: @Val And does that mean they will remove the concept of type, because of the fact that every single index has one single type?

Comment: Yes, in ES 7, types will not exist anymore and an index will consequently only contain a single mapping.

Comment: @Val Thank's for explanation, I would follow this in my index creating . Also I think it would be less confusing to have only indexes

Comment: @SimpleCode the call your looking for is `client.Map<T>(...)` for 5.x, with caveats Val has highlighted.

Comment: @RussCam Thanks for replying