# In ElasticSearch i have to create single index and multiple types or multiple index with single types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in elastic search.I am using elastic search for big data.

There is not join query in my application then which structure is best for my application?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465668/elastic-search-multiple-indexes-vs-one-index-and-types-for-different-data-sets ... in summary: your only option is the second one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on elasticserach from past few days. I would like to share my experience/learnings.

1) If we moving from relational DB like MYSQL, SQL to `ES`, We need to maintain all relation among all data. Declare the primary key in different types or indexes, On basis of which you can perform Query DSL.

2) In case of if you dealing with millions data everyday, You need to design accordingly. Some people prefer duration based structure like `Day, Week, Month` wise. Its totally depend on your use case. For large data set (~ 1TB) you need to distribute your data in various of `indexes` and `shards` .

3) If you have small data set the it will be work in default settings too (`5 shrads 1 replica`). It will give you better If data set is small in your `shards`.

4) The `JOIN` query can be expensive in elasticsearch. And if you frequently performing it can be impact to your `HEAP`. So I would suggest prepare your data set with `pre-cooked` data (The result data which you getting when you perform join query in Relational DBs.) & document with unique ID. You can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html). Check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) to look, How we can perform `JOIN`

5) There might be some points which you need to take care while designing your index:

1. Don't treat Elasticsearch like a database
2. Know your use case BEFORE you jump in
3. Organize your data wisely
4. Make smart use of replicas
5. Base your capacity plans on experiment

6) Your wrong architecture can cause `reindex` which will be heavy cost with downtime. Checkout [this article](https://bonsai.io/2016/01/11/ideal-elasticsearch-cluster/) to know about `index designing` and best practices.