# Elastic search get document by type and index vs only index

Tags: elasticsearch

http://localhost:9200/corp/_doc/1/?pretty

It works

http://localhost:9200/corp/employee/_doc/1/?pretty

It doesn't work.

When I replace `_doc` by `_search` it works in both the cases. I do understand the difference between search and get a doc by id.

My doubt is that when should I specify both type and index. In my first case, don't we need type as another type in the same index can have the same id.

I am completely new to ELK and exploring with a definitive guide. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index types (`employee` in your case) are [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). It's customary now to have one type per one index (`_doc`).

- `GET corp/_doc/1` will get you the corp doc with id#1.
- `GET corp/_doc/_search` is deprecated in favor of `GET corp/_search`
- `GET /corp/employee/_doc/1` is invalid because `employee` and `_doc` are both types. Use either `/corp/employee/1` in older ES versions or `/corp/_doc/1` in newer ones

Comment: Are you saying that we can have only one type per index?

Comment: That's right. The index name should make the type clear.

Comment: Out of this context. So index is just a namespace. If so, we can have one of index/type. Isn't? Is there any particular use case? Does top voted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465668/elastic-search-multiple-indexes-vs-one-index-and-types-for-different-data-sets) are no more fully correct?